# remove reference title when using \usepackage{apacite}

Tags: ref

I am using the {apacite} package for referencing, however I would like to remove the title 'reference' which is auto input my {apacite} so that I can create a section called REFERENCES and have it numbered as previous sections.

I have seen other posts for removing the title, but not using the {apacite} package.
thanks

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[vmargin=1.25in,hmargin=1.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{times}               % Times Roman
\usepackage[scaled=0.86]{helvet} % Helvetica

\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\large\sffamily}
\usepackage[nosectionbib]{apacite}

\begin{document}
\raggedright
\hrule
\begin{center}
\huge\bfseries\sffamily Title is using arial
\end{center}
\hrule

\section*{ABSTRACT}

\cite{7050699}

Correctly using Times Roman 

\section{INTRODUCTION}

Correctly using Times Roman


\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{sa.bib}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a numbered bib, use the option `numberedbib`. You can redefine `\refname` to change the title:

```
\usepackage[nosectionbib,numberedbib]{apacite}

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\refname{REFERENCES}}
```

[image]

Comment: perfect thanks @Ulrike Fischer that gave the exact result I wanted ! many thanks